# I want to display the Email Id and Mobile number in masked format in drupal7? Suggestions needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

Example.

```
raju327@gmail.com
9999888877
```

Output

```
rajuXXX@gmail.com 
999XXXX877
```

And also core i want to use the OTP functionality to be fixed with button click OTP password only customer should change username and password.

Comment: Share more example and your try please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check working example,**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   MobEncrypt();
   EmailEncrypt()
});

function MobEncrypt() {
var value = '9999888877';
    // make a string with x-characters
    var x = new Array(value.length - 3).join('X');
    // join this string with the tail of the value, and replace it
    alert(x + value.substr(value.length - 3));
}

function EmailEncrypt() {
var value = 'raju327@gmail.com';
    // make a string with x-characters
    var x = new Array(value.length - 5).join('X');
    // join this string with the tail of the value, and replace it
    alert(x + value.substr(value.length - 5));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```